# How can i crawl web data that not in tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests

```
<div id="main-content" class="content">
<div class="metaline">
<span class="article-meta author">jorden</span>
</div>
 "
 1.name:jorden> 
 2.age:28

  --
 "
 <span class="D2"> from 111.111.111.111 </span>
  </div>
```

I only need

> 1.name:jorden
>   2.age:28

`xxx.select('#main-content')` this will return all things, but i only need part of them.
Because they are not in any tags, i don't know how to do.

Comment: any link of the website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the tag *before* the text in question (in your case, `<div class="metaline">`) and then look at the *next* sibling in the HTML parse tree:

```
text = soup.find("div", class_='metaline').next_sibling
print(text)
# "
# 1.name:jorden> 
# 2.age:28
#
#  --
# "
#
```

Once you get the raw text, strip it, etc.