# How can i crawl web data that not in tags(class name is same)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Sorry.
I have asked a question like this.
After that i still have problem about data not in tag. 
A few different the question i asked 
([How can i crawl web data that not in tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124862/how-can-i-crawl-web-data-that-not-in-tags/44124963#44124963))

```
<div class="bbs" id="main-content">
    <div class="metaline">
        <span class="article-meta-tag">
             author
        </span>
        <span class="article-meta-value">
             Jorden 
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="metaline">
        <span class="article-meta-tag">
            board
        </span>
        <span class="article-meta-value">
            NBA
        </span>
    </div>

I am here

</div>
```

I only need

> I am here

Comment: `I am here` is still in a `div` tag (main-content), it's just not in CERTAIN div tags (class=metaline).  Knowing that, this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is a child of the main `div` of type `NavigableString`, so you can loop through div.children and filter based on the type of the node:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
[x.strip() for x in soup.find("div", {'id': 'main-content'}).children if isinstance(x, NavigableString) and x.strip()]
# [u'I am here']
```

*Data*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class="bbs" id="main-content">
    <div class="metaline">
        <span class="article-meta-tag">
             author
        </span>
        <span class="article-meta-value">
             Jorden 
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="metaline">
        <span class="article-meta-tag">
            board
        </span>
        <span class="article-meta-value">
            NBA
        </span>
    </div>
I am here
</div>""", "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(that_html)
div_tag = soup.div
required_string = div_tag.string
```

go thought [this documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)